# How to pull the merge of two tables with a relational filed in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two rather large tables in an SQL, they share one column to do the relational analysis.

I want to pull only around 10,000 entries from a merged table, so I don't have to query for the whole database.

I want to do this as generic as possible, so let's say we have one table with fields A,B,C and another with C,D,E. Each table has around 3 million entries. And my output should be a table with A,B,C,D,E with only 10,000 entries.

Thanks!

Comment: use `join` and (`Top` or `limit`) based on the RDBMS

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: MS SQL, in Azure

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    A, B, C, D, E 
from 
    table1 t1 
inner join 
    table2 t2 on t1.c = t2.c 
limit 3000000
```

Comment: you do not even know which sql product he is using

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer in SQL Server

```
select top(10000) A, B, C, D, E 
into t3
from t1 join t2 on t1.pk = t2.fk
```

Here is an answer in MySQL

```
create table t3 as 
select A, B, C, D, E
from t1 inner join t2 on t1.pk = t2.fk
limit 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT k.A,k.B,k.C,k.D,k.E
  FROM
        (
            SELECT t1.A,t1.B,t1.C,t2.D,t2.E,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t1.c ) AS rn
              FROM table1 t1
            INNER JOIN
                  table2 t2
                ON t1.c = t2.c
         ) k   
 WHERE k.rn <= 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select top 10000
    A, B, C, D, E 
from 
    table1 t1 
inner join 
    table2 t2 on t1.c = t2.c
Order by newid ()

With the above query we will get 10k random records.